# WCF REST on Azure fails with "413 Request Entity Too Large"

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-binding, azure-web-roles

I have deployed a RESTful WCF service on Azure. One of the contract operations is supposed to take image files (not larger than 500kb), which are uploaded from the clients. Currently, my solution is running without any problems in the Azure computer/storage emulator. However, when I deploy the solution to Azure, an upload from the client (image size is 133kb) fails with 413 Request Entity Too Large. It seems like Azure is ignoring the configuration I have set in web.config (which is correctly picked up in the Azure emulator).

Any help on how to solve this issue will be highly appreciated. Below are the relevant snippets of my code.

Interface

```
namespace HappyBabiesSvc
{
    [ServiceContract]    
    public interface IHappyBabies

[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/v1.0/locations/{locationID}/images",
        Method = "PUT")]
    void UploadNewImage(string locationID, Stream imageToUpload);
```

Service Implementation

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="HappyBabiesSvc.HappyBabiesSvc" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>    
    <standardEndpoints>      
      <webHttpEndpoint>        
        <standardEndpoint maxReceivedMessageSize="655360"/>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false"/>
    <services>
      <service name="HappyBabiesSvc.HappyBabiesSvc" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceConfiguration">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
          name="HappyBabiesService"
          contract="HappyBabiesSvc.IHappyBabies" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding maxBufferSize="655360"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="655360" transferMode="Streamed">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="655360" maxStringContentLength="655360"
          maxArrayLength="655360" maxBytesPerRead="655360" maxNameTableCharCount="655360" />
      </binding>
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this? I have a similar issue with Azure completely ignoring my configuration as well and I'm also getting 413 errors from an Azure WCF service.

Comment: Yes. The problem was that visual studio was not uploading the config files as part of the deployment. Enable rdp on your instance, log in remotely and manually copy the config files to see if your problem has the root cause as mine.

Answer (score 0):

Try only method with single parameter that is Stream .
Stream parameter should be alone.

> [OperationContract]
>   [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/v1.0/locations/{locationID}/images",Method = "PUT")]
>       void UploadNewImage(Stream imageToUpload);

Comment: please check https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/48facfba-15d4-4e7e-998f-7e88ff9afc21/wcf-restful-services-running-on-azure-fails-with-413-request-entity-too-large?forum=windowsazuredevelopment